# Scoring is updating only once then after not updating

Tags: unity-game-engine

When knife is colliding with the fruit score is updating but only once like from 0 to 10 then after it's not updating can any one solve them
I tried some other possible ways but not happening

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class FruitCutter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject halfFruitPrefab; // Drag the half-fruit model here
    public AudioClip sliceSound;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;

    public int currentScore = 0;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Knife"))
        {
            scoreText.text = "collision detected";
            // Play sound effect
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(sliceSound, transform.position);

           
            currentScore += 10;
            UpdateScoreText();
            scoreText.text = "Score incremented to: " + currentScore;

            // Create half fruits
            Instantiate(halfFruitPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(halfFruitPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

            // Destroy original fruit
            //Destroy(gameObject);
            gameObject. SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    void UpdateScoreText()
    {
            //scoreText.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
        scoreText.text = "Updating score display! Current Score: " + currentScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this code is on every fruit right?  well then currentscore on each instance is 0, therefore each fruit that cuts takes it from 0 to 10.

Comment: yes sir code is applied to orange fruit. so how to make a change like then after every slicing the points should update

Comment: well to be fair, your fruit should not be responsible for your overall score.   But in as in all programming there are many ways to achieve something, some more crazy than others, but, this is  in large, down to your choices and preferences and other requirements..   I would probably have some game manager handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Like BugFinder said, you should probably have a different class handle that.

if you don't want to do that, you could make the score variable static.

so instead of  `public int currentScore = 0;`you could declare it as

`public static int currentScore = 0;`and that way it should get updated across instances.

Not a super smart way of doing it, but it should work.